# Reading column value in cell change event

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've an .net winforms screen with infragisitics ultrawingrid bound from the database[Col Names:Id, Name, Age].
Am adding a checkbox column for each row from the client side while showing the grid.
Am capturing cell change event when the checkbox is clicked by the user.

In method attached to this event, I want to read the values of the all the cells for the row which is in context...[for eg.I want to read Id,Name,Age column values].How do I progammatically do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UltraGridColumn ugc = myGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[@"myColumnKey"];

private void mygrid_CellChange(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
{
    if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(e.Cell.Column.Key, @"myColumnKey"))
    {
         //something like this
         ugc [@"myColumnKey"][index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried this,but am getting an error: cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type UltraGrdiColumn.

Comment: Ok..I got it..i tried this and it worked for me:e.Cell.Row.Cells[0].Value. Thanks for ur inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in the `ultraGrid1_ClickCell_1` event

```
///
/// Select value in cell one 
/// 
_load = (int)e.Cell.Row.Cells["LOAD"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
grdAssignedACL_CellChange( ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs) Handles grdAssignedACL.CellChange
```